# Convert yml to application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a filter in spring boot that recieves a token from aws  cognito httpservletrequest and authenticates to use my api.

The last thing I need to do is add some properties to my application.properties.

Unfortunely I only have it in yml format.

```
com:
  ixortalk:
    security:
        jwt:
          aws:
            userPoolId: "us-west-2_abcdefghi"
            identityPoolId: "us-west-2:xxxxxxxx-aaaa-bbbb-ccc-dddddddddddd"
            region: "us-west-2"
```

How do I convert this to properties?

Have anyone used https://github.com/IxorTalk/ixortalk.aws.cognito.jwt.security.filter/blob/master/README.md to authenticate with cognito against a spring boot server? Is there something better out there?

Comment: could you plz format your yml snippet => use ``` <your code comes here....> ``` - maybe I can help then

Comment: Yes i'm on it. Created the question on my cellphone :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `application.properties` should workout that way:

```
com.ixortalk.security.jwt.aws.userPoolId=us-west-2_abcdefghi
com.ixortalk.security.jwt.aws.identityPoolId=us-west-2:xxxxxxxx-aaaa-bbbb-ccc-dddddddddddd
com.ixortalk.security.jwt.aws.region=us-west-2
```